# Criterion for unramified prime in number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime in $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}\cap\mathcal{O}_K$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ generates the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_{L,\mathfrak{q}}$ of the localization ring $\mathcal{O}_{L,\mathfrak{q}}$, then how to prove the ramification index $e(\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{p})$ is $1$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak q_1, ... , \mathfrak q_g$ be all the primes of $\mathcal O_L$ lying over $\mathfrak p$.  The definition of the ramification index $e = e(\mathfrak q /\mathfrak p)$ is

$$\mathfrak p \mathcal O_L = \mathfrak q^e \mathfrak q_2^{e_2} \cdots \mathfrak q_g^{e_g}$$

as ideals of $\mathcal O_L$.  If we localize these ideals to $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak q}$, we have

$$(\mathfrak p \mathcal O_L)_{\mathfrak q} = \mathfrak p \mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak q}$$

$$( \mathfrak q^e \mathfrak q_2^{e_2} \cdots \mathfrak q_g^{e_g})_{\mathfrak q} = \mathfrak q^e \mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak q}$$

since the other prime ideals $\mathfrak q_i$ generate the unit ideal in $\mathcal O_{L,\mathfrak q}$.

Comment: Also in OP's setting $\mathfrak p \mathcal O_L$ is maximal thus $=\mathfrak{q}$